# How do I extract embedded payloads from a Wix burn installer?

Tags: wix

I have some embedded as well as remote payload in a Wix burn installer.

I use /layout option to get remote payloads. Is there any option to extract embedded ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is an open [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/feature-requests/692/) for that.